Maximum of real polynomials in terms of its coefficients
Given a closed bounded intervals $[a,b]$, any polynomial
$$p(x)=a_0+a_1 x+\dots+a_n x^n,$$ with $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$, has an absolute maximum on $[a,b]$. That is there exist $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$p(c)=\max_{[a,b]}p(x).$$ This is an immediate consequence of the maximum value theorem of continuous functions on compact sets.
Is there a general formula to compute $c=c(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n)$?
For instance, if $a_i>0$ ($a_i<0$) for all $i$, and $a>0$, then $c=b$ ($c=a$).
That is impossible in general, I imagine, without adding some restrictions on the coefficients.
Where can one learn about this basic problem ?

I don't believe there is any general formula that finds a point where the polynomial has a maximum. There are general algorithms for isolating the roots of a polynomial. If you apply one of these algorithms to the derivative of your polynomial you will be able to isolate the local maxima and then locate the global maxima to within any desired degree of tolerance.
